# AJAX foreach $_POST merge values

Tags: php, ajax

I'm gonna try to be as clear as possible.

I'm currently working on a project for my work, with dynamic forms where the form inputs are in a database, and created dynamically. Every input row looks something like:

```
Question? Radiogroup Textinput
```

And when the user press submit in a section of maybe 3-5 of these rows the form is serialised and managed with AJAX. So here comes the part I'm having trouble with, as of now, in my AJAX file, there is a foreach loop which loops through all $_POST values, adds them to an array and then after the array is complete all data is inserted to a SQL database. And I don't know if it's a problem since I'm not a professional DBA, but there's a lot of rows being inserted to the database, since EVERY radio group, and EVERY text input, gets their own row. And I was thinking if I at least could cut it down to every question getting their own row, but how do I then merge the radio group value with the text input value so they are on the same row but different columns.

I hope I'm being clear enough here.
Database layout today

```
|ID|RowID|Type|User|Value
```

Where Type is either Radio or Text. What I want to achieve to get half of the rows I'm gonna get this way is:

```
|ID|RowID|Type|User|Radio|Text
```

And the problem is howto achieve this when my foreach loop fills an array with a lot of rows, for each form, which as I say, is containing maybe 3-5 rows with both a radio group and a text input. This is how I do it today:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $values[] = "'{$id}', '{$user}', '{$type}', '{$value}'";
}

$mysqli->query('INSERT INTO data (rowid, user, type, value) VALUES ('.implode('),(', $values).')');
```

Hope someone can help me out.

Best Regards
Cisco

Comment: **No no no.** Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) when dealing with untrusted data.

Comment: I always do that, but why should I include that above when that has nothing to do with the problem at hand..

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by doing the following:

```
//Only define for testing.
$_POST['rad_1'] = "yes";
$_POST['rad_2'] = "no";
$_POST['rad_3'] = "yes";

$_POST['txt_1'] = "Test";
$_POST['txt_2'] = "Test2";
$_POST['txt_3'] = "Test3";

$array = array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

    $keyarr = explode('_', $key);
    $type = $keyarr[0];
    $id = $keyarr[1];
    $value = $value;

    $array[$id][$type] = $value;
}

$values = array();

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $values[] = implode(', ', $value);
}


$query = "INSERT INTO table_name test VALUES (" . implode ("),(", $values) . ")";
```